# Single-use password for download

Tags: php, security, passwords

What is the best approach for implementing a single-use password to download a file?  Initially I thought about using PHP, assigning a password to a user and, upon them logging in removing the account. I would keep the account in a file as I don't expect to ever have more than a handful of valid users at any given time. Do I need to track sessions or is there a simple way to accomplish this with a single site?

Oh, I cannot use an external site as the data is sensitive and must be kept locally nor can I download any new software and thus am limited to HTML, JavaScript and PHP (I believe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much just a combination of Ilmari Karonen's and martinstoeckli's answers, but with more detail.

Using this sort of database table:

```
temp_passes

uuid  | createTime | expireTime | filename
------------------------------------------
123-4 | 1326735047 | 1327735047 | myDisk.iso
```

Somehow, you generate a UUID for the user, and insert it into the database. Then, when giving a download link, you use the UUID like so:

http://example.com/download.php?id=123-4

or alternatively, have a password field where the user has to enter in their ID, and submit it to `download.php`. Either way:

1. Validate the ID against the database, ensuring it exists and hasn't expired.
2. Delete the ID from the database, so it cannot be used again.
3. Let PHP generate the download, likely using [`readFile()`](http://ca.php.net/readfile).

You can choose to delete the ID either before or after the download has finished, that's up to you. However, if it's a large file, you'll likely want to do it first so that other people cannot use the same "password" to have multiple simultaneous downloads.

Comment: I completely forgot that I wrote this answer, and found myself implementing such a system late last year. Happy to see that I followed my own advice without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a simple PHP script that checks the password against a [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) stored on the server (either in a file or in a database) and, if it matches, delivers the file using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile).  Once you've successfully sent the file, remove the password from the list or mark it as disabled somehow.

(Yes, I realize that this answer is very vague and generic, but then, so is your question too.  If you can clarify what it is that you're unsure about, I might be able to give a better answer.)

Comment: Can this be accomplished with a single site?  I'm not familiar with how to use sessions with php.  Can I 1)ask for the password and 2) deliver the file with a single site?  Or does this require two server pages and the need to track sessions?  Yes, the question was a bit vague as I'm a bit new to this and not knowledgable enough to ask a very detailed question.

Comment: Yes, you generate a hash server-side and store it with the filename, and provide the hash to the user. When a user enters a hash, the server sends the corresponding file.

Comment: @WildBill: You will need a form where the user can enter the password (unless you just want to send them a link with the password already in it) and a script that receives the password and sends the file.  The script can also show the form, if you like, or the form can be on a separate page (which can be just plain HTML, no PHP needed).  You won't need sessions for this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to offer a one-time-action, not a real login. You can do this creating a UUID and building a link with it, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/action.php?act=129d1e24-16f1-11e1-99fe-66756e647a65
```

This UUID you would have to store on the server (database), together with the information of which file the user can download. After the user clicked the link, he can download just this file, and when the download has finished, you delete the UUID from the database.